Google calendar event does not use colorId that has been set in server
We have system that actually integrates with Google Calendar by creating event there. When create event, we also let user to set the color based on their preference. Technically, we pass colorId when calling Create Event API
However, when we open the created event on Google Calendar GUI (both web and mobile app), it doesn't use colorId that has been set previously. Looks like their GUI uses color that is set in client
Is there any way to let Google Calendar GUI (both web and mobile app) uses color based on colorId that has been set in the server?
I've ensured that colorId has been set correctly in server by calling their Get Event API
Expect: in GUI, use color based on colorId in server

To use color based on the colorId that has been set on the server, you can use the insert method from the Google Calendar API. You can test this by visiting the Google Developers article for the “insert” method, and using the APIs Explorer from the right pane.
Here’s an example of this request in action:
{
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2024-07-10T18:30:00+03:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Bratislava"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2024-07-10T19:30:00+03:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Bratislava"
  },
  "summary": "EventTitle",
  "colorId": "5"
}

First, you can use the user’s email address as the calendarId. Alternatively, you can retrieve the IDs of the calendars on the user’s list by using the CalendarList.list method. This can help if the user has multiple calendars and you need to identify which one to use.
Next, you can define the event’s time range using the start and end properties. Each of these properties should have:

dateTime: The start and end times of the event in ISO 8601 format.

timeZone: The time zone for the event times.


You can also use the summary property I highlighted in the code above in order to set the title of the event. Finally, in order to set the event color, you can use the colorId property to specify the color of the event. The colorId corresponds to a predefined set of colors on the server.
This is the set of predefined colors based on the response of colors.get:
"event": {
  "1": {
   "background": "#a4bdfc",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "2": {
   "background": "#7ae7bf",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "3": {
   "background": "#dbadff",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "4": {
   "background": "#ff887c",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "5": {
   "background": "#fbd75b",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "6": {
   "background": "#ffb878",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "7": {
   "background": "#46d6db",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "8": {
   "background": "#e1e1e1",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "9": {
   "background": "#5484ed",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "10": {
   "background": "#51b749",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  },
  "11": {
   "background": "#dc2127",
   "foreground": "#1d1d1d"
  }
 }


Hi Nicolas, thanks for the answer. Actually we've done it. We've called insert/create event to Google Calendar API along with predefined colorId. The problem is, what actually shown in google calendar web client (in user pov) is still the default color, somehow. Not the color we've defined previously.
